# How to set azure key vault values as kuberetes environment variable (without read from the filesystem)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I have a c# application that runs in the Kubernetes cluster. my application pods have to read the values from azure keyvalut. Currently, I'm using CSI driver and read the values from the filesystem.
Is there any option to set key valut values as environment variables and read?.

Comment: What do you use for the CSI driver? Azure disk or Azure file?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this: https://github.com/SparebankenVest/azure-key-vault-to-kubernetes

it can be used, this open-source project sync the key values from the vault to Kubernetes secrets and you can inject that secret inside the pod as the environment variables.

your application directly reads the value of a key from the environment based on language.

for example with python :

```
import os
print(os.environ['TEST'])
```

you can find the documentation at : https://akv2k8s.io/how-it-works/